# using laravel blade templates without php

Tags: php, laravel, template-engine, laravel-blade

I want to let people upload template files but I don't want them to be able to run PHP code (and looking at the blade docs it looks like people can). Any ideas? Or if I should be looking at another solution what would be a good one?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Blade is not a good solution for this - it's basically an alternative syntax for PHP.

Something like [Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/) is a better option - it doesn't allow raw PHP code, and you can additionally whitelist only specific functions/attributes/etc. in its sandbox mode. Users have access only to the stuff you want them to have.